# If HTTP/2 is enabled, Jetty Stop-Port is not working

Tags: java, jetty, http2

I'm working with the Jetty standalone Version 9.3.9 (start.jar) and got the following issue:

The Jetty has SSL enabled and can only be accessed via https. The start and stop of the jetty-server is managed by two shellscripts, which defines the stop-port and the stop-key:

```
java -DSTOP.PORT=PORT -DSTOP.KEY=secret start.jar
```

*PORT and KEY are just placeholders*

Via the `--stop` parameter the Jetty server stops correctly.
Now when the module `http2` is enabled (it works perfectly) and the stop script is executed, i receive the following error (first line is translated).

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.stop(Main.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.stop(Main.java:491)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.doStop(Main.java:479)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:403)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

and the server does not shut down. Inspected with `ps aux` there are also now two processes, one of them does contain the following line and is also spawned when `http2` is disabled:

```
java -DSTOP.PORT=PORT -DSTOP.KEY=secret
```

The other (new) one contains a huge ugly call to java and it looks like it's loading different resources via `Xbootclasspath`

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:lib/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar 
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Djetty.home=jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9 
-Djetty.base=jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9/myappbase 
-cp jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.
ecj-4.4.2.jar:jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9/lib/apachejsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9/lib/apache-
```

... and so on. Probably it belongs to `ALPN` which is used by `HTTP/2`.

As soon as http2 is disabled (for example when the folder start.d is renamed), the studown via port and key work's again.

*Edit2, added output of start.jar --list-config:*

```
Java Environment:
-----------------
java.home = jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9/jdk1.8.0_91/jre
java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version = 25.91-b14
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.info = mixed mode
java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_91-b14
java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
user.dir = jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9/myappbase
user.language = de
user.country = DE

Jetty Environment:
-----------------
jetty.version = 9.3.9.v20160517
jetty.tag.version = master
jetty.home = jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9
jetty.base = jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9/myappbase

Config Search Order:
--------------------
<command-line>
${jetty.base} -> jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9/myappbase
${jetty.home} -> jettyfolder/jetty-9.3.9

JVM Arguments:
--------------------
-Xbootclasspath/p:lib/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar

System Properties:
------------------
(no system properties specified)

Properties:
-----------
java.version = 1.8.0_91
java.version.major = 1
java.version.minor = 8
java.version.revision = 0
java.version.update = 91
jetty.ssl.port = 8200
jetty.sslContext.keyManagerPassword = SOMEPASSWORD(placehoder)
jetty.sslContext.keyStorePassword = SOMEPASSWORD(placehoder)
jetty.sslContext.keyStorePath = etc/keystore
jetty.sslContext.trustStorePassword = SOMEPASSWORD(placehoder)
jetty.sslContext.trustStorePath = etc/keystore
Jetty Server Classpath:
-----------------------
Version Information on 15 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
    changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
0:                    3.1.0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar
1:                 3.1.0.M0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar
2:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-http-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
3:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
4:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-xml-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
5:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
6:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
7:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-security-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
8:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
9:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-alpn-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
10:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-webapp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
11:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-deploy-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
12:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/http2/http2-common-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
13:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/http2/http2-hpack-9.3.9.v20160517.jar
14:          9.3.9.v20160517 | ${jetty.home}/lib/http2/http2-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar

Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml
${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-ssl.xml
${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-ssl-context.xml
${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-alpn.xml
${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-deploy.xml
${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-http2.xml
${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-https.xml
```

Comment: Run this and update your question with the output ... `$ cd /path/to/myappbase && java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --list-config`

Comment: with or without http2?

Comment: since it happens with http2, i say have the http2 module enabled with you list the config.

Comment: I added the output of start.jar --list-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

Instead of adding 
`-DSTOP.PORT=PORT -DSTOP.KEY=secret` to the call of the java binary, I simply added it to the `start.ini` file of the jetty server.
The first two lines of my `start.ini` now looks like:

```
-DSTOP.PORT=PORT 
-DSTOP.KEY=secret
```

and it works! I guess the exact position in the configuration file does not matter. Also both parameters are now not longer visible with `px aux`.

Answer (score 0):

The option `-DSTOP.PORT=PORT` is invalid as declared.

The value should be a port number, that Jetty has the permissions to bind to.

Pick a number between 1025 and 65534 and use that.

Eg:  `-DSTOP.PORT=27272`

Comment: It's is just a placeholder, i will update my question to make it more clear